# Переключение между вкладками в Atom

Tags: atom

Как можно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии клавиш <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> переключиться на следующую вкладку и при нажатии на <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> - на предыдущую в редакторе Atom, как в браузерах?

Comment: У атом по умолчанию так и стоит, можете посмотреть File->Settings->Keybindings

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте следующий код в ваш [keymap.cson](http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/basic-customization/#_customizing_keybindings):

```
'body':
 'ctrl-tab': 'pane:show-next-item'
 'ctrl-shift-tab': 'pane:show-previous-item'
```

Также в Atom по умолчанию к <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd> и <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd> прикручены действия `'pane:show-next-recently-used-item'` и `'pane:show-previous-recently-used-item'`. Если будет мешать, можно переназначить в том же файле:

```
'ваши-клавиши-сюда': 'pane:show-previous-recently-used-item' 
'ваши-клавиши-сюда': 'pane:show-next-recently-used-item'
```